# Executing bash for loop in a python Jupyter notebook cell

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to run a bash for loop in a cell of my Jupyter notebook. I can re-write the command on one line and prefix it with `!` and it runs fine, but I like the format for readability (teaching notebook). Using the `%%bash` magic command doesn't seem to work.

```
%%bash
for sample in $(cat samples)
do
    echo "On sample: $sample" 
    cutadapt \
    -g ^GTGYCAGCMGCCGCGGTAA \
    -G ^CCGYCAATTYMTTTRAGTTT \
    -m 209 -M 255 \
    --too-short-output untrimmed_fastq/${sample}_R1_too-short.fastq.gz \
    --too-long-output untrimmed_fastq/${sample}_R1_too-long.fastq.gz \
    --untrimmed-output untrimmed_fastq/${sample}_R1_untrimmed.fastq.gz \
    --too-short-paired-output untrimmed_fastq/${sample}_R2_too-short.fastq.gz \
    --too-long-paired-output untrimmed_fastq/${sample}_R2_too-long.fastq.gz \
    --untrimmed-paired-output untrimmed_fastq/${sample}_R2_untrimmed.fastq.gz \
    -o trimmed_fastq/${sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz -p trimmed_fastq/${sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz \
    fastqfiles/${sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz fastqfiles/${sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz \
    >> cutadapt_stats.txt 2>&1
done
```

Yields the syntax error:

```
File "<ipython-input-3-592002da22aa>", line 3
    for sample in $(cat samples)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm fairly new to using magic commands and subprocesses. Thank you for any tips or insight

Comment: use subprocess module, ex. subprocess.run()

Comment: could you please give me an example of the correct syntax in the above example or a dummy for loop - pretty new to this - thanks

Comment: What is 'samples' supposed to be? I didn't get any error when I ran the code as it is in a notebook cell after creating samples.txt file with some text in it.

Comment: 'samples' is just a list of sample names, one on each line of a text file. The command runs in terminal. I can't get it to run in a notebook running a python kernel.